# Endless loop in SAP ABAP adobe forms

Tags: adobe, abap

I've done everything on the interface,selects etc, passed the info on the form. Eventually when I try to execute it from the driver program, after selecting the printing device , clicking the print preview, it stays endlessly loading without returning nothing. I entered with debug mode , and the info was passed correctly.
 Any idea ?

Comment: Don't start the debug before it goes into the endless loop, start the debug **during** the endless loop, by using SM50 or SM66 transaction code. You'll get directly into the endless loop (if it's really an endless loop).

Comment: I'm not clear yet, please be more concret, how do I proceed ?

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. You're asking for debugging help without providing much information. This tends to lead to general answers, that usually don't help.
Do standard printing programs work? Did you try placing breakpoints in the interface?  Do you have any scripts in the form? Do you have any special logic in your code?

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely that the problem is caused by an infinite loop (or some super heavy calculations, that take a while to execute) in the code you've written, and not by the standard functionality, which means we really cannot help you without knowing the code.

---

Now to your problem.
You will probably find your problem in 1 of 3 places (**using basic debugging techniques**):

**[PDF FORM SCRIPTS]** 
If you have any scripts written in PDF form, I suggest you use a clean (empty new form with the same interface for testing. PDF form script debugging would require its own question and I'm not getting into it here.

If you had pdf form scripts written launch the program with a clean form and see if it still gets stuck. If it doesn't - problem is in your scripts, if it does - continue to next step.

**[PRINTING PROGRAM]** If you are using using your own (non-standard) printing program to call PDF function module, place a breakpoint on call of PDF function module call and `job close` function module.

Launch the program and see if the function module of PDF form and `job close` function module ever gets called (I assume it does, because you see the Printing pop-up). If neither is called, you have an endless loop before even getting to pdf function module. If PDF FM gets called multiple times, but not the `job close` one, your pdf function module is in an endless loop. If both get called the problem is not in program.

**[FORM INTERFACE]** If you have any logic in your interface code, place breakpoints (by writing `break-point` in code) at the end of the interface code.

When you run the program, the breakpoint at the end should trigger. (if it does not - look for a loop / long running code in your interface.

If the problem is in the interface or program, place a breakpoint at the start of it, and look at how the program executes step-by-step, to find where it get stuck.

---

You can also use a different approach, that Sandra Rossi suggested, and start a debugger while your program is stuck. Bare in mind, this will only help you if it actually is an endless loop (it won't help to find bad selects, bad configurations, etc).

To do that, launch your program in 1 session and when it gets stuck open `SM66` transaction in another session. Find your program in the list (of `SM66`), select it (by clicking the left-most column) and select **Administration** -> **Program** -> **Debugging** from menu. A debugger should open and the "current step" of the program should be be somewhere within your endless loop (if there is one).

---

Since you provided no code, or any data, I assume you can correct the problem on your own, once you find it.

If it is none of those things, update your answer with some details, and maybe you will get a more specific answer.